# Finite Field Homomorphism

Tags: finite-fields

Let's say that I have a finite field K with characteristic 2. I define @ as a map where 
@ : K -> K, and 
    x -> $x^2$.

First of all, what are some examples of fields like K? I initially thought it would only be 0 and 1 with addition and multiplication mod 2, but apparently more elements can exist so long as 1+1=0.

Secondly, how would one begin to prove that @ is an automorphism?

Answer (score 2):

First, the prime field of characteristic $2$ is $\mathbb{F}_2 = ℤ/2ℤ$.

Then, for any irreducible polyonmial $p ∈ \mathbb{F}_2[X]$ of degree $1$ or greater, you can form the factor ring $\mathbb{F}_2 [X]/(p)$ which turns out to be a field. These are examples (and the only examples) of finite fields of characteristic $2$. I don’t know if you already know about this, but otherwise you should make yourself familiar with polynomial rings and a bit of ideal theory.

The argument that such a ring $\mathbb{F}_2 [X]/(p)$ forms a field is as follows:

- $\mathbb{F}_2 [X]$ is a euclidian ring, hence a principal ideal domain.
- Therefore, $p ∈ \mathbb{F}_2 [X]$ is irreducible if and only if $(p) ⊂ \mathbb{F}_2 [X]$ is a *maximal ideal*.
- A factor ring is a field if and only if the ideal factored out is maximal.

If you want to show that for a finite field $K$ of characteristic $2$, the [Frobenius morphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_morphism) $@\colon K → K$ is an automorphism, it suffices to check *five* things:

- It is additive – this follows from the binomial theorem/formula and the fact that $2 = 0$ in $K$.
- It is multiplicative – because exponentiation in commutative rings always is.
- It preserves the identity – $@(1) = 1$ which indeed should not be neglected as pointed out by Nishant² in the comments.
- It is injective – because it is a *field homomorphism* as just checked and field homomorphisms always have trivial kernel and are hence injective.
- It is surjective – because it is injective and domain and codomain are finite of the same cardinality.

---

By the way, [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) knows about the finite fields of characteristic $2$, e.g. of $\mathbb{F}_4$, the [field with four elements](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=finite+field+of+order+4). You can try out other fields of characteristic $2$, just search for finite fields of any order which is a power of $2$.

Comment: Technically, you'd have to check that 1 is sent to 1 for it to be a field homomorphism. Without that condition, you could send everything to 0.